# Filter JSON by value spring java

Tags: java, json, spring, jira

I'm trying to filter an incoming JSON by it's value. This is the current JSON that I generate by receiven a huge JSON from an jira api. I have a few POJO classes that handle the response and get only the fields I need for now. But I need the "fromString" and "toString" keys which only contain a handful Strings, like "To Do", "Done", "QA To Do". I tried using FilterProvider but I don't know how to filter by value and then add it to my GetMapping.

This is my current GetMapping in my controller class, which creates a response and filters the items[] only for the key "fromString":

```java
    @GetMapping("/")
    public MappingJacksonValue run() throws Exception {
            IssuesList response = rest.getForObject(
                    "https://.../rest/api/2/search?jql=project="+projectId+ " AND status in (done) AND issuetype in (Story)&expand=changelog",
                    IssuesList.class);

              List<Issues> issuesData = response.getIssuesList();

        MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(issuesData);
        FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("itemsEntity", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("fromString"));
        mappingJacksonValue.setFilters(filterProvider);

        log.info(mappingJacksonValue.toString());
        return mappingJacksonValue;
    }
```

My Pojo class with items:

```java
@Data
@JsonFilter("itemsEntity")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Items {

    @JsonProperty("fromString")
    private String fromString;
    @JsonProperty("toString")
    private String toString;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" +
                "fromString= " + '\'' + fromString+ '\'' +
                ", toString= " + '\'' + toString +  '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is the current JSON that I produce from the response I get, I want it to skip all "fromString" and "toString" keys which do not contain one of the following: "To Do", "Done","Qa To Do", etc.
How do I achieve that?

```json
[
    {
        "key": "PE-1322",
        "fields": {
            "issuetype": {
                "name": "Story"
            },
            "created": "2020-11-18T09:16:55.816+0000",
            "customfield_10105": 3
        },
        "changelog": {
            "histories": [
                {
                    "created": "2020-12-17T08:57:28.800+0000",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "fromString": "This issue relates to TD-353"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "created": "2020-12-17T08:57:19.233+0000",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "fromString": null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write your own Filter that uses a comparator that suits your needs.

For example:

```
filteredList = Arrays.stream(unfilteredList).filter(listItem -> listItem.contains("To Do")).toArray(String[]::new);
```

In this case the filter will filter out anything that doesn't contain the string "To Do".

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick answer. I'm not able to understand how I could implement your solution. Do you have any keywords or subjects I could read to understand this better?